# Is possible to call javascript nested function new fun1().fun2().fun3()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, javascript-objects, nested-function

This is my orginal function

```
   function fun1(){
     this.fun2 = function(){
        this.fun3 = function(){
        } 
     }
    }
```

when I call function

```
new fun1().fun2()
```

its working fine, but when I use

```
new fun1().fun2().fun3()
```

its not working. I need to work nested function call like

```
 new fun1().fun2().fun3()
```

Comment: While it may be possible to achieve something similar to this, it's not good practice. As such this seems like an XY question, where you're asking about an attempted solution instead of describing the problem you're trying to solve. If you could give details of why you feel the need to do this, we can offer better solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote both `fun1` and `fun2` in the form of a constructor (uses `this`, does not return a value). Constructors, if invoked using the `new` keyword, produce a new object.

Thus, `new fun1()` returns an object that has `.fun2`. But `obj.fun2()` returns `undefined`, since it has no `return`, and `new` was not used, which is why your `.fun3` call doesn't work. You would need to write one of these:

```
new (new fun1().fun2)().fun3()         // if `fun3` is a function
new (new (new fun1().fun2)().fun3)()   // if `fun3` is a constructor
```

to execute `fun3` in your scenario. As Rory says, this code is almost certainly a bad idea.

In order for chaining `new fun1().fun2().fun3()` to work, `fun1` should be a constructor that creates an object that `fun2` method, which returns an object that has `fun3` method. An obvious scenario is when these objects are the same object, but it is not necessarily so. The easiest scenario where your chaining code would work would be

```
class fun1 {
  fun2() {
    return this;
  }
  fun3() {
  }
}
```

Or equivalently

```
function fun1() {
}
fun1.prototype = {
  fun2: function fun2() {
    return this;
  },
  fun3: function fun3() {
  },
};
```

Or almost-but-not-quite equivalently:

```
function fun1() {
  this.fun2 = function fun2() {
    return this;
  }
  this.fun3 = function fun3() {
  }
}
```

You can also write it so that the two intermediate objects are different:

```
class Other {
  fun3() {
  }
}

class fun1 {
  fun2() {
    return new Other();
  }
}
```

(or the equivalent, or almost-equivalent code)

Also note that constructors are conventionally named using TitleCase; this notifies the programmers who read the code of how it is supposed to be used. Thus, `Fun1` should be strongly preferred over `fun1` — though it is not an error to do otherwise.

(NB. I talk about a difference between constructors and functions; in fact, there is no difference. I merely write so as a shortcut for "a function written in such a way that it is expected to execute it as a constructor", and "a function which is written in such a way that it should be invoked as a normal function".)

Comment: Expanding on this answer, attempting to accomplish something like the scenario in the question is almost certainly an indicator that either the code is structured incorrectly or an attempt is being made to force the wrong solution for the given problem. Clear, easy to understand code trumps complicated "clever" code any day of the week. Unless your project is complex enough to benefit from the additional architectural burden, it's almost always a better idea to avoid solving a problem that you don't actually have to solve.

Comment: @B.Fleming True. Though note that sometimes chaining is the desired design, like with jQuery (where almost every method returns `this`). The OP's function as written was misguided, though the goal might not be.

Comment: Absolutely true. It's a classic chicken and the egg problem. If it's a solution in search of a problem, then it should be avoided, but if it's a legitimate problem in search of a solution, then that's a different matter entirely.

Comment: Love the clarity of this answer. I'm trying to understand the consequences of using the "almost equivalent" technique for chaining. I see that we're spawning copies of `fun2` & `fun3` for each instance of `fun1` instead of just referencing them in `fun1.prototype`, and I know this could be a waste of memory -- What else happens to the relationships between our objects as a result of this design choice?

Comment: @Cat As you say, the difference is just whether the methods are inherited from prototype, or added to each instance. One consequence is the memory consumption; another one is whether `new fun1().fun2 === new fun1().fun2` is true or false. A more useful difference, not used here, is that the separate-function-per-instance could [close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) over some of the surrounding variables, which is obviously not possible if you have the same function on multiple objects.